# SFINAE overload on tuples of different sizes

Tags: c++, tuples, overloading, sfinae

Consider a struct that contains two types - `FirstObjects` and `SecondObjects`, which are both `std::tuple<>`, e.g. something like:

```
struct Objects
{
    using FirstObjects = std::tuple<int, int>;
    using SecondObjects = std::tuple<int>;
};
```

For convenience we add the following enum:

```
enum class ObjectCategory
{
    FIRST,
    SECOND
};
```

Now consider the following class that is templated on a type such as `Objects` as described above (the only contract is that it have `FirstObjects` and `SecondObjects` and that they be `std::tuple`):

```
template <typename T>
class SomeClass
{
public:
    using FirstObjects = typename T::FirstObjects;
    using SecondObjects = typename T::SecondObjects;
    
    template <std::size_t Idx>
    using FirstObject = typename std::tuple_element<Idx, FirstObjects>::type;
    template <std::size_t Idx>
    using SecondObject = typename std::tuple_element<Idx, SecondObjects>::type;        
    
    template <ObjectCategory Category, std::size_t Idx>
    using ObjectType = std::conditional_t<Category == ObjectCategory::FIRST, FirstObject<Idx>, SecondObject<Idx>>;
    
    template <ObjectCategory Category, std::size_t Idx>
    std::enable_if_t<Category == ObjectCategory::FIRST, const ObjectType<Category, Idx>>& getObject()
    {
        return std::get<Idx>(firstObjects_);
    }

    template <ObjectCategory Category, std::size_t Idx>
    std::enable_if_t<Category == ObjectCategory::SECOND, const ObjectType<Category, Idx>>& getObject()
    {
        return std::get<Idx>(secondObjects_);
    }    
    
    template <ObjectCategory Category, std::size_t Idx>
    void doSomething()
    {
        const ObjectType<Category, Idx>& obj = getObject<Category, Idx>();
    }
    
private:
    FirstObjects firstObjects_;
    SecondObjects secondObjects_;
};
```

In brief, `SomeClass` hosts two member variables, `firstObjects_` of type `T::FirstObjects`, and `secondObjects_` of type `T::SecondObjects`, and has a `doSomething()` function which makes use of the SFINAE-overloaded `getObject()` getter method that returns the i-th object contained in firstObjects_ or in secondObjects_ depending on the `ObjectCategory` chosen.

The problem I have now is:

```
int main()
{
    struct Objects
    {
        using FirstObjects = std::tuple<int, int>;
        using SecondObjects = std::tuple<int>;
    };    
    SomeClass<Objects> object{};
    object.doSomething<ObjectCategory::FIRST, 0>(); // <------ works fine
    object.doSomething<ObjectCategory::FIRST, 1>(); // <------ compiler error
}
```

The last line makes the compiler complain:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.9/tuple: In instantiation of 'struct std::tuple_element<1ul, std::tuple<int> >':
70:114:   required by substitution of 'template<class T> template<ObjectCategory Category, long unsigned int Idx> using ObjectType = std::conditional_t<(Category == FIRST), typename std::tuple_element<Idx, typename T::FirstObjects>::type, typename std::tuple_element<Idx, typename T::SecondObjects>::type> [with ObjectCategory Category = (ObjectCategory)0; long unsigned int Idx = 1ul; T = main()::Objects]'
87:42:   required from 'void SomeClass<T>::doSomething() [with ObjectCategory Category = (ObjectCategory)0; long unsigned int Idx = 1ul; T = main()::Objects]'
104:50:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.9/tuple:682:12: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct std::tuple_element<0ul, std::tuple<> >'
     struct tuple_element<__i, tuple<_Head, _Tail...> >
            ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/tuple:38:0,
                 from 4:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/utility:85:11: error: declaration of 'struct std::tuple_element<0ul, std::tuple<> >'
     class tuple_element;
           ^
 In substitution of 'template<class T> template<ObjectCategory Category, long unsigned int Idx> using ObjectType = std::conditional_t<(Category == FIRST), typename std::tuple_element<Idx, typename T::FirstObjects>::type, typename std::tuple_element<Idx, typename T::SecondObjects>::type> [with ObjectCategory Category = (ObjectCategory)0; long unsigned int Idx = 1ul; T = main()::Objects]':
87:42:   required from 'void SomeClass<T>::doSomething() [with ObjectCategory Category = (ObjectCategory)0; long unsigned int Idx = 1ul; T = main()::Objects]'
104:50:   required from here
70:114: error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::tuple_element<1ul, std::tuple<int> >'
```

It seems like it is not liking the fact that `SecondObjects` only has one element and therefore `std::get<1>(secondObjects_)` is not working? But why is this even happening in the first place since I'm calling `doSomething` on `ObjectCategory::FIRST` and not `ObjectCategory::SECOND`?

How can this be solved?

------ EDIT 1 ------

Solution pointed out by @Taekahn is to change the `getObject()` method as follows:

```
    template <ObjectCategory Category, std::size_t Idx>
    const auto& getObject()
    {
        return std::get<Idx>(firstObjects_);
    }

    template <ObjectCategory Category, std::size_t Idx, typename = std::enable_if_t<Category == ObjectCategory::SECOND>>
    const auto& getObject()
    {
        return std::get<Idx>(secondObjects_);
    }
```

It seems like the above works because the compiler does not evaluate / check the validity of the return type of a method that has been SFINAE'd out when one uses the keyword `auto` instead of the explicit type.
But this is only conjecture - would really appreciate a more knowledgeable C++ practitioner to weigh in here!

------ EDIT 2 ------

The above results in ambiguity when trying to do

```
    object.doSomething<ObjectCategory::SECOND, 0>();
```

The WAR I've found so far is to modify the first getter function to

```
    template <ObjectCategory Category, std::size_t Idx, typename = std::enable_if_t<Category == ObjectCategory::FIRST>, bool = 0 /* dummy param */>
    auto& getObject()
    {
        return std::get<Idx>(firstObjects_);
    }
```

i.e. to add the SFINAE as well as a dummy template arg at the end to allow overloading.

Comment: The reason this is happening is because `std::enable_if_t<Category == ObjectCategory::SECOND, const ObjectType<Category, Idx>>` evaluates BOTH parameters to the template. Just because the first parameter evaluates to false does not prevent the 2nd parameter from getting evaluated, and failing. This is not short circuit evaluation. I'm pretty sure that this can be made to work by making `std::enable_if_t`, sans its 2nd parameter, as a default third template parameter of the method itself, but it's a lot of work to double-check, and I'm too lazy today.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.
I tried doing this 
```
    template <ObjectCategory Category, std::size_t Idx, typename = std::enable_if_t<Category == ObjectCategory::FIRST>>
    const FirstObject<Idx>& getObject()
    {
        return std::get<Idx>(firstObjects_);
    }

    template <ObjectCategory Category, std::size_t Idx, typename = std::enable_if_t<Category == ObjectCategory::SECOND>>
    const SecondObject<Idx>& getObject()
    {
        return std::get<Idx>(secondObjects_);
    }
```
and it still complains with the same error.

Comment: Its really hard to tell, but i think your return type is wrong. I would try to pair your example down a bit to just what's needed to reproduce, if you can. Also, maybe try auto deducing the return types? Also, any restriction on your C++ version?

Comment: Yes it seems the compiler is evaluating the return type even when the method itself is supposed to be SFINAE'd-out... I tried using auto (with trailing return types otherwise it's not allowing me to overload), to no avail. I also tried not returning the object but passing it as a non-const reference argument of the method instead, to no avail. C++ restricted to <=14.

Comment: Does this not work for you? https://godbolt.org/z/4WTnqddcs

Comment: @Taekahn wow, it seems to work - thanks! Why do you think that is?
Is it because in your solution, the compiler does not need to evaluate / check the validity of the return type of a method that has been SFINAE'd out when one uses `auto`?

Comment: @zhanginou that is my theory. But I’m not smart enough to say it with any authority.

Comment: @Taekahn now though, doing object.doSomething<ObjectCategory::SECOND, 0>(); makes the compiler complain - error: call of overloaded 'getObject()' is ambiguous...

Comment: @Taekahn The WAR I've found for now is to change the getter for the first object to be template <ObjectCategory Category, std::size_t Idx, typename = std::enable_if_t<Category == ObjectCategory::FIRST>, bool = 0>, i.e. with the SFINAE as well + a dummy extra template param at the end to allow overloading.

Comment: @zhanginou yeah, I figured you would have to. I meant to do it but ran out of time